# Can I pass this function to another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote this, but not work

Can javascript function pass self to other function

Can I also access the variable in the caller function?

```
function caller()
{
    var variable=123;
    calledfunction(this);
}
function calledfunction(caller)
{
    console.log(caller.variable);
}
caller();
```

Comment: There are several key things wrong here. It also looks like you're trying to implement a callback but really only need a simple return.

Comment: What is `filter` and where is `calledfunction` called from?

Comment: Just revised the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var variable` in the assignment to `this.variable`:

```
function caller()
{
    this.variable=123;
    calledfunction(this);
}
function calledfunction(caller)
{
    console.log(caller.variable);
}
caller();
```

In this case `caller` is not really generating a new instance/scope so `this` is actually global which is bad. It would be better to create a new empty object and use that to hold data instead of using `this`.

```
function caller()
{
    var data = {};
    data.variable=123;
    calledfunction(data);
}
function calledfunction(values)
{
    console.log(values.variable);
}
caller();
```

Alternatively you can use a closure in this case by putting `calledfunction` inside `caller`:

```
function caller()
{
    var variable=123;
    calledfunction();

    function calledfunction()
    {
        console.log(variable);
    }
}
caller();
```

Comment: You should clarify that in the first case you are really just playing with global variables, which is generally discouraged (`this === window`).

Comment: @FelixKling, Good point. I added a third example that creates an empty object to hold the data instead of using `this`.